# Getting this error when i run the program in eclipse as well as using Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. Host info: host: 'DESKTOP-0EJ1KML', ip: '192.168.29.117' Build info: version: '4.17.0', revision: 'e52b1be057*' System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.8.1' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platformName: Windows 10}]}] Capabilities {browserName: chrome, platformName: Windows 10}

Comment: Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints and edit your question to provide *much* more information - ideally a [mcve].